# Need Help in Reversing the arrayElements and getting exception

Tags: java

Am not getting out put to reversing the arrayElements and am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at testcases.ReveringInput.main(ReveringInput.java:20).
```

Here is my code

```
package testcases;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReveringInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Size of an Array");
        int Size = in.nextInt();
        int [] array = new int[Size];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of an Array");
        int i;

        for(i=0; i< Size ; i++)
        {
            array [i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        for(i= Size ; i <= Size ; i--)
        {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: `i= Size ; i <= Size` but there is no element with index "Size", use `i = Size - 1; i > 0` or better, use enhanced for-loop `for (int x : array)`

Comment: Your second loop starts with `i= Size`, and `array[Size]` doesn't exist .

Comment: `for(i= Size ; i <= Size ; i--)` ... You intentionally iterate until the underflow? Really?

Answer (score 2):

You wrote

`for(i= Size ; i <= Size ; i--)`

An array initialized with size `Size` only goes from 0 all the way to `Size - 1` so modify it to `i=Size -1` then you wrote `i <= Size` which it will always be so it will infinitely run this code which isn't good, you need to change it to `i>=0` instead it should work after these modifications

Comment: Oawsome !!!! it worked Saloomi, thats for the great help but can u help me understanding the logic behind this plzz....

Comment: @chandramouli if you liked my answer, you can mark my answer as the solution. The reason you change it into `i>=0' is because you want to start from the end all the way to the first element  (0)

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the Size of an Array");
int size = in.nextInt();
int[] array = new int[size];
System.out.println("Enter the elements of an Array");

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    array[i] = in.nextInt();
}

for(int i = size-1; i > -1; i--)
{
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

To explain the second for loop:

- `int i = size-1`: Start `i` from the highest array index. For example if `size == 5`, then `array[4]` gives you the last element.
- `i > -1`: Run the loop until `i` is 0 or positive.
- `i--`: Decrease `i` by one after each iteration.

Hope this helps!